# Conditional expectation of a Poisson Process

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Given a Poisson process with parameter $q$, and if $X$ is the number of arrivals during $(0, 1]$, then what is $E(X | X > 0)$?

Could I use the memorylessness of the process to write:
$1 + E(X)$?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $X$ has Poisson distribution with mean $q$, we compute
$$
\mathbb E\left[X\mid X>0\right] = \frac{\mathbb E\left[X\mathsf 1_{\left\{ X>0\right\}}\right]}{\mathbb P(X>0)} = \frac{\mathbb E\left[X\right]}{\mathbb P(X>0)} = \frac q{1-e^{-q}}.$$